# ExperimentalDecorators Warning

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, visual-studio-code

I had an application with Angular 4, and I tried test with jasmine and Karma. But this error it occurred.

Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a
 future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

this  is my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "strictMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

I just edited settings.json of VScode and put this code

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create the file `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` you can just enable **experimentarDecorators** for all your projects in Visual Studio Code:

1. File > Preference > Settings
2. Search: **experimentalDecorators**
3. Enable the checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue. I followed these steps to solve the problem:

1- Add this line to my Visual Studio Code settings:
 "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,

2- Add the option   "experimentalDecorators": true, to the compilerOptions of the tsconfig.json file of the project. (As you already have in your code)

And my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You will still get the error message if you click on any relevant declaration while Visual Studio Code has your project open in too narrow a scope, i.e. when VSC doesn't know your tsconfig.json file even exists, because it's not open in your folder view.